# Fill in table with date and cause year and month (postgresql, javascript)

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I have this table with a date column:

| fecha | hora | folio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-04 | 16:40 | 1 |
| 2022-04-05 | 18:20 | 2 |
| 2022-04-06 | 13:20 | 3 |

I need to extract the year and month an used, so I used this query:

```sql
select fecha, extract(month from fecha) = 3 as mes, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha) = 2022 as anio, hora, folio from table;
```

I get:

| fecha | mes | anio | hora | folio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-04 | true | true | 16:40 | 1 |
| 2022-04-05 | false | true | 18:20 | 2 |
| 2022-04-06 | false | true | 13:20 | 3 |

I need only the rows where `mes` and `anio` are `true`, but the `WHERE` clause doesn't recognize `mes` and `anio` as columns of the table.

Instead, I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "mes" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._medicion from medicion where r_fisico = true and mes = true...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 353
```

I need this values for a `<input type='month' />`

Comment: What's your full query (where clause and all)

Comment: select fecha, extract(month from fecha) = 3 as mes, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha) = 2022 as anio, hora, folio from table where anio = true and mes = true;

Comment: Are you using NodeJS, or is this the browser SQL database?

Comment: yes, I'm using NodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using sub-query.

Basically wrap your query with another select, and place the `WHERE` condition outside.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        fecha, 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fecha) = 3 AS mes, 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha) = 2022 AS anio,
        hora,
        folio 
    FROM table 
) t
WHERE t.anio = true and t.mes = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the sequence each phase of the SQL statement is processed. The column alias is assigned as the select `list` is processed however `where` clause is processed *before* the select `list`. Thus the assigned **alias does not exist** when the `where` clause is processed. You basically have three options:

Extract the values (with alias) in a sub-select (or CTE) then select with `where` referencing the alias.

```
select * 
  from (
        select fecha
             , extract(month from fecha) = 3 as mes
             , extract(year froM fecha) = 2022 as anio
             , hora
             , folio 
          from table
        ) 
  where mes = true 
    and anio = true;
```

Repeat the evaluation for mes and anio (without the actual alias).

```
select fecha
     , extract(month from fecha) = 3 as mes
     , extract(year froM fecha) = 2022 as anio
     , hora
     , folio 
  from table 
 where extract(month from fecha) = 3
   and extract(year froM fecha) = 2022 ;
```

Rewrite with `where` referencing just the date itself.

```
 select fecha
     , extract(month from fecha) = 3 as mes
     , extract(year froM fecha) = 2022 as anio
     , hora
     , folio 
  from table 
 where date_trunc('month', fecha) = date '2022-03-01';
```

**Note** None tested.